# Getting Infinite Loop While Trying to Parse Through A DataFrame Variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to parse through a dataframe variable, which is defined as follows:

```
data_enum = pandas.read_csv("data_enum.csv")
```

This csv file has 63089 rows and 9 columns. My goal is to iterate through a column in data_enum and convert the strings to numeric values. More specifically, it is to tokenize the strings and convert them to their associated token ids.

Here is the code I have used to do this:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer

for i in range(len(data_enum)):
    if [data_enum.iat[i, 3]] in app_list:
       word = data_enum.iat[i, 3]
       tz = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")   
       tz.convert_tokens_to_ids(["characteristically"])'''
       data_enum.iat[i, 3] = tz.convert_tokens_to_ids(tz.tokenize(word))
```

For whatever reason, this leads to an infinite loop or causes the program to hang. In theory, it should not hang or cause an infinite loop because I'm iterating through the range from 0 to the length of the data frame.

Can anyone figure out why this might not be working?

Comment: It's not an infinite loop.  Perhaps it's just taking a long time?  Put a `print(i)` n the loop or do a `for i in range(10)` and time processing 10 tokens.

Comment: You can save a lot of time by pulling the BertTokenizer just once at the very beginning and outside of the loop.

Comment: In general, try to avoid writing explicit loops over dataframe rows, use its built-in functions for processing the entire df at once. These loops are in optimized C code, so they're much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

the code itself might be causing the infinite loop issue. you are trying to check if list is available in `app_list`, this will return `False` because the list will not be found as an element in 'app_list".

This might help:

```
if data_enum.iat[i, 3] in app_list:
```

By removing the square bracket you are directly checking if the value at position `(i, 3)` in `data_enum` is present in `app_list`

Answer (score 0):

Create a small cut of your data with like 100 lines for testing. As others have already suggested, this is most probably not an infinite look, only one that takes very very long. Probably whatever happens in there takes really really long. Put in a

```
print(".", end = "")
```

in the loop to see if it iterates or not. (It surely does)